# SQL 4 table query

Tags: php, sql, join

I have this code:

```
if ($firearm != "") { 
  $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT icon FROM db_firearms WHERE name='$firearm'", $db); 
  $rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5); $firearm_icon=$rs5[icon]; 
  }

if ($item != "") {
  $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT icon FROM db_items WHERE name='$item'", $db); 
  $rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5); $item_icon=$rs5[icon]; 
  }

if ($vehicle != "") { 
  $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT icon FROM db_vehicles WHERE name='$vehicle'", $db); 
  $rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5); $vehicle_icon=$rs5[icon]; 
  }

if ($melee != "") {
  $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT icon FROM db_melee WHERE name='$melee'", $db);
  $rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5); $melee_icon=$rs5[icon];
  }
```

This code is being refreshed every 10 seconds on a part of my page showing the players equipment. Would it be best to have this in one query, to save db resources?

If so, how would I write that? Would it be INNER JOINS? normal JOINS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use a union, with a bit of fireproofing in case you get no match on a name:

**Code example to work around broken DB-design**

```
$sql = "
  (SELECT 'fire' as id, icon FROM db_firearms WHERE name='$firearm' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'item' as id, icon FROM db_items WHERE name='$item' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'vehi' as id, icon FROM db_vehicles WHERE name='$vehicle' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'melee' as id, icon FROM db_melee WHERE name='$melee' LIMIT 1)
";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['id'] == 'fire') {$fireicon = $row['icon'];}
    elseif ($row['id'] == 'item') {$itemicon = $row['icon'];}
    elseif ($row['id'] == 'vehi') {$vehiicon = $row['icon'];}
    elseif ($row['id'] == 'melee') {$meleeicon = $row['icon'];}
  }
}
```

The `union all` stops MySQL trying to eliminate duplicates, speeding up the query.

**Better solution**

You should really put all your icons in one table

```
TABLE icons
  user_id
  icon_type ENUM('gun','item','melee','vehicle')
  icon blob
  primary key (user_id, icon_type)
```

Now you can select

```
SELECT icon_type, icon FROM icons WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

But of course this really depends of the details of your application.
My point is just that UNION is a warning sign that you're doing something wrong or **unusual**

Comment: im assuming id need to do it like SELECT icon as f_icon FROM db_firearms, so i dont have 4 of the same record names?

Comment: @user1022585, that's it. Don't go overboard on UNION though, it is not something you should use a lot. It's really a sign that your DB is not properly designed.

Comment: @user1022585: no, unions make all the individual queries appear as a single one. If you need to keep track of which sub-query a particular result came from, you'd have to add an extra derived field. `select 'firearms' as source, con from db_firearms ... union select 'items' as source, icon etc...`.

Comment: @user1022585, the record names will be the same, you just need to fetch the row 4 times, in the order you selected them.

Comment: what so like $firearm_icon=$rs[icon]; $melee_icon=$rs[icon] ??

Comment: @user1022585, there was a ',' missing in the SQL, causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be best to have this in one query, to save db resources?

No.

Comment: I disagree, why ping the server 4 times, when you can union this in one go.

Comment: @jadarnel27 this is a question of the kind "I have no idea where to optimize or even if i need to but I have a silly idea on the matter"

Comment: Oh.  How fantastically condescending of you.

Comment: Asking is how you get the ideas... Didn't you get the memo?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, agreed on the badness of the table layout. This code smacks of bad database design.

Comment: I am getting ideas after doing hard research and investigation.

Comment: @Johan not too much. if a vehicle happen to have a "speed" stat while melee a "hit" one it is well-known complicated task of keeping them in one table. I'd use a mongo for this task nowadays.